# Rails - how can I use ajax to reorder a subset of a larger list

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-sortable

I have links and groups (of links).
I have a groups show page that shows one group and the members it contains.

How can I reorder the links and have the state saved to the database?

I've added jquery-ui and used .sortable so I can actually move the li rows in the ui.
Now I need to add the rails code to save this sort.  How do I do this?
All the examples I see are for a full list and the whole list gets re-written so the index of the loop can be used.
Mine however look like:

```
<ul>
<li id='361'>
  <a href="http://www.w.com" title="www.w.com">w.com</a>
  -             &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/links/361" title="">details</a>            &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/links/361/edit" title="">edit</a>
</li>
<li id='362'>
  <a href="http://www.snap2web.com" title="www.snap2web.com">snap2web.com</a>
  -             &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/links/362" title="">details</a>            &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/links/362/edit" title="">edit</a>
</li>
<li id='363'>
  <a href="http://http://www.w.commm" title="htttp://www.w.commm">htttp://w.commm</a>
  -             &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/links/363" title="">details</a>            &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/links/363/edit" title="">edit</a>
</li>
<li id='365'>
  <a href="http://www.testabc.com" title="www.testabc.com">testabc.com</a>
  -             &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/links/365" title="">details</a>            &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/links/365/edit" title="">edit</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

If the positions for these three elements are 15,21,209,65  How can I reorder them in the groups controller?

I'm currently adding this in the HAML doc:

```
%script
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('UL').sortable({
         axis: 'y',
         dropOnEmpty: false,
         handle: '.handle',
         cursor: 'crosshair',
         items: 'li',
         opacity: 0.4,
         scroll: true,
         update: function () {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/links/sort',
                 type: 'post',
                 data: $('#links').sortable('serialize'),
                 dataType: 'script',
                 complete: function (request) {
                     $('#links').effect('highlight');
                 }
             });
         }
     });
 });
```

and was planning to add something like this to the groups controller:

```
def sort
  @links = Group.find(:id).links
  @links.each do |link|
    link.position = params['link'].index(link.id.to_s) + 1
  book.save
  render :null
end
```

but not sure if this is the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the case to assume the current_user who'll sort this list is the only man who can save the order to db.

In this case you need one extra field in `Link` to save the changed sequence. Let's name it `seq`. It will be the major method to order the links.

Then, for jQuery part, I find [toArray](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray) would be simple to use, instead of current `'serialize'`, with others untouched.

The jQuery ajax will post to `sort` method in controller. And the `params[:links]`(I'm not sure about the key, just assume it's `links`) will be an array of ids.

```
# GroupsController
def sort
  ids = params[:links]
  ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
    link = Link.find(id)
    link.seq = index
    link.save
  end
end

# Then always ship links with order of seq
def show
  group = Group.find(params[:id])
  @links = group.links.order('seq ASC')
end
```

Just a note that my implementation `sort` method is not efficient that there are multiple queries executed. A better approach would be construct custom sQL to update in a batch. This is just a quick answer to present the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try with this.

In the controller to show the list ul/li

```
@links = Group.find(:id).links.order('position')
```

In the HAML

```
= text_field_tag :id_list, @links.map{|link| link.id.to_s}.join(',')
=#YOUR rails code to populate the li goes here
```

In the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('UL').sortable({
     axis: 'y',
     dropOnEmpty: false,
     handle: '.handle',
     cursor: 'crosshair',
     items: 'li',
     opacity: 0.4,
     scroll: true,
     beforeStop: function(event, ui){
       // get the id_list of the li separated by ','
       var id_list = "li".map(function(i, n) {
                       return $(n).attr('id');
                       }).get().join(",");

       if(id_list != $('#id_list').val()){
           $.post('/links/sort', 
             {id_list: id_list},
             function(res){
               // YOUR CODE GOES HERE. 
            });
       }
   });
});
```

In the sort action

```
def sort
  list_id_arr = params['id_list'].split(',')
  list_id_arr.each_with_index.map{|list_id, i| Link.find(list_id).update_attribute(:position, i+1)}
  render :text => 'true'
end
```